# Best approach for moving tempdb .ndf files

Tags: sql-server, configuration, tempdb, alter-database

During a SQL Server installation, I "thought" I specified location of tempdb on 'F:' and  not 'C:', but I can see that although tempdb.mdf and templog.ldf are on 'F:', the 3 .ndf secondary data files are on 'C:'.

I'm thinking of moving the .ndf files by performing following steps:

  1.

```sql
    ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = temp2 , FILENAME = 'F:\MSSQLData\temp2' )
    ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = temp3 , FILENAME = 'F:\MSSQLData\temp3' )
    ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = temp4 , FILENAME = 'F:\MSSQLData\temp4' )
```

2. Stop SQL Server (the instance isn't doing anything currently).
3. copy/paste the 3 .ndf files from their current C: location to the new F:\MSSQLData\ location
4. Restart SQL Server.
5. Check if it worked:

```sql
    SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc  
    FROM sys.master_files  
    WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');
```

Is that the best approach? The instance supports only 3 small databases (<10GB total).

Comment: [Moving the tempdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#a-moving-the-tempdb-database) section has the exact steps. You do not need step 3 and delete the file from `c:` once you are done with step 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is the one you can find on the [Moving the tempdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15) section of the documentation.

Your method is close to the one Microsoft recommends, except by the **2nd** and  **3rd** steps you listed and the reason is:

> Because tempdb is re-created each time the instance of SQL Server is
> started, you do not have to physically move the data and log files.

Remember to manually delete the files from the old location after step 5.

Comment: This means the old files are left behind though? So they need to be manually cleaned up?

Comment: @BJury, the old files should be manually deleted. SQL Server only deletes the old files to create new ones at startup when the file location is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if the files doesn't exist, then they are created at startup. So the question is whether to delete them from the old location and lest SQL Server creates new ones? Or to move the files so SQL Server don't have to create new ones? One could argue that one of these would be quicker than the other. If that isn't an issue, then use whichever feels best for you.

One factor is whether you have Instant File Initialization turned on. Without it, you'll se a longer time to create data files.

My guess is that for that file size, you won't see any significant difference. I.e., use whichever method.