# Why can't I remove the tempdb's first data file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Under tempdb properties, I have 1 data file and 1 log file.

I have now added a 2nd data file.

Now when I click on 1st data file, the remove button is disabled. Why is that and how can I delete the 1st data file?

Comment: are you willing to change tempdb files from disk? If so, see [Best approach for moving tempdb .ndf files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251615/best-approach-for-moving-tempdb-ndf-files).

Answer (score 1):

that is because the first file specified becomes the primary file. A database can have only one primary file. Primary file contains startup information for the database and points to the other files in the database. Every database has one primary data file. The recommended file name extension for primary data files is .mdf.

Comment: How to make the 2nd data file primary so that I can delete the 1st data file?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?